# spdep "Not yet able to subset general weights lists" listw

Tags: r, regression, geospatial, spatial, spdep

I have a problems with `spdep()`. Starting with a matrix of non-missing distances produced by a function

```
dist_m <- geoDistMatrix(data1, group = 'fips_dist')
dist_m[upper.tri(dist_m)] <- t(dist_m)[upper.tri(dist_m)]
```

we then turn into weights with linear inverse

```
max_dist <- max(dist_m)
w1 <- (max_dist + 1 - dist_m)/(max_dist + 1)
```

and now

```
lw <- mat2listw(w1, row.names = rownames(w1), style = 'M')
```

I check to make sure no missing weights:

```
any(is.na(lw$weights))
```

and since there aren't, go ahead with:

```
errorsarlm(cvote ~ inc, data = data1, lw, method = 'eigen', quiet = F, zero.policy = TRUE)
```

leads to the following error:

```
Error in subset.listw(listw, subset, zero.policy = zero.policy) : 
  Not yet able to subset general weights lists
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because at least one observation in `data1` is not complete, i.e. has missing values. Hence, `errorsarlm` wants to subset the data, i.e. restrict to complete cases. But it can't do it now - that's what the error message says.

Best is to subset the data manually or correct the incomplete cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the spdep function created a listw object only for non-general weights by default. Set `zero.polcy=TRUE` beform you perform `mat2listw` or `nb2listw` function so that it consider non-neighbors that have zero value.